# Group by function in JavaFX table

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

We are migrating swt/nattable applications to the new java8 and Javafx8.

Everything is going smooth but one feature of nattable cannot be found. The feature we are searching for is the "group by" feature. So we need a library/implementation to drag/drop columns on a label and with those columns a group by in the table. Can someone help us with this?

How the group by feature is working in Nattable.

There are two main components the table itself and the dropzone of the different columns. When a user drag a columns to the dropzone the table will groups the values of that column together (like the Group by in SQL). After that the table will show the result of that group by operation.

Comment: Can you explain more fully what the functionality is, for those not familiar with nattable?

Comment: Added some more details description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at the srouce of James_D I found a way to implement the group by feature I'm looking for. Here the full source code of my group by feature in JavaFX.

```
public class Main extends Application {

    List<Employee> employees = Arrays.<Employee>asList(
            new Employee("Ethan Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com", "A"),
            new Employee("Emma Jones", "emma.jones@example.com", "B"),
            new Employee("Michael Brown", "michael.brown@example.com", "A"),
            new Employee("Anna Black", "anna.black@example.com", "C"),
            new Employee("Rodger York", "roger.york@example.com", "B"),
            new Employee("Susan Collins", "susan.collins@example.com", "A"));

    final TreeItem<Employee> root =
            new TreeItem<>(new Employee("Sales Department", "", ""), null);

    Label dropLabel;

    BreadCrumbBar breadcrum;

    private Comparator<Employee> groupingComparator;

    private ArrayList<String> comperatorList = new ArrayList<>();

    Map<String, Function<Employee, Comparable>> gettersMap = new HashMap<>();

    private TreeTableView<Employee> treeTableView;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{


        stage.setTitle("Tree Table View Sample");
        final Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(), 400, 400);
        scene.setFill(Color.LIGHTGRAY);
        Group sceneRoot = (Group) scene.getRoot();


        root.setExpanded(true);
        employees.stream().forEach((employee) -> {
            root.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>(employee));
        });

        gettersMap.put("Employee", Employee::getName);
        gettersMap.put("Email", Employee::getEmail);
        gettersMap.put("Test", Employee::getTest);

        TreeTableColumn<Employee, String> empColumn = column("Employee", Employee::getName);
        empColumn.setPrefWidth(150);
        empColumn.setCellValueFactory(
                (TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Employee, String> param) ->
                        new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(param.getValue().getValue().getName())
        );

        TreeTableColumn<Employee, String> emailColumn = column("Email", Employee::getEmail);
        emailColumn.setPrefWidth(190);
        emailColumn.setCellValueFactory(
                (TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Employee, String> param) ->
                        new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(param.getValue().getValue().getEmail())
        );

        TreeTableColumn<Employee, String> testColumn = column("Test", Employee::getTest);
        testColumn.setPrefWidth(190);
        testColumn.setCellValueFactory(
                (TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Employee, String> param) ->
                        new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(param.getValue().getValue().getTest())
        );

        treeTableView = new TreeTableView<Employee>(root);
        treeTableView.getColumns().setAll(empColumn, emailColumn, testColumn);

        breadcrum = new BreadCrumbBar<>();

        breadcrum.setOnCrumbAction(new EventHandler<BreadCrumbBar.BreadCrumbActionEvent<String>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(BreadCrumbBar.BreadCrumbActionEvent<String> event) {
            }
        });

        dropLabel = new Label("Use the shift key when you select a column to group");

        dropLabel.setOnDragOver(e -> {
            if (groupingComparator != null && "Group".equals(e.getDragboard().getString())) {
                e.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY);
            }
        });

        dropLabel.setOnDragDropped(e -> {
            if (groupingComparator != null && "Group".equals(e.getDragboard().getString())) {

                comperatorList.add(((Label) e.getGestureSource()).getText());

                String selectedColumn = ((Label)e.getGestureSource()).getText();

                if(breadcrum.selectedCrumbProperty().get() == null) {

                    TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<String>(selectedColumn);

                    breadcrum.selectedCrumbProperty().set(root);
                }
                else
                {
                    TreeItem<String> root = (TreeItem<String>) breadcrum.selectedCrumbProperty().get();

                    TreeItem<String> child = new TreeItem<String>(selectedColumn);
                    root.getChildren().add(child);

                    breadcrum.selectedCrumbProperty().set(child);
                }

                try {

                    String comperatorString = "";

                    for (String temp : comperatorList)
                    {
                        comperatorString += temp + ";";
                    }

                    comperatorString = comperatorString.substring(0, comperatorString.length()-1);

                    Comparator<Employee> comparator = getComparator(comperatorString);

                    ArrayList<Employee> allItems = new ArrayList<Employee>();
                    getChildren(root, allItems);

                    Collections.sort(allItems, comparator);

                    ArrayList<String> compareValues = new ArrayList<String>();

                    ArrayList<TreeItem<Employee>> parents = new ArrayList<TreeItem<Employee>>();
                    parents.add(0, this.root);

                    this.root.getChildren().removeAll(this.root.getChildren());

                    for(Employee item: allItems)
                    {
                        for(int i =0; i < comperatorList.size(); i++)
                        {
                           Method getMethod = item.getClass().getMethod("get" + this.comperatorList.get(i), null);

                            String result = (String) getMethod.invoke(item);

                            if((compareValues.size() <= i  || !result.equals(compareValues.get(i))))
                            {
                                TreeItem<Employee> newItem = new TreeItem<Employee>(new Employee());
                                newItem.setExpanded(true);

                                parents.add(i+1, newItem);

                                parents.get(i).getChildren().add(newItem);

                                compareValues.add(i, result);
                            }

                            //Add leafs to tree
                            if(i == comperatorList.size() -1 || (i == 0 && comperatorList.size() == 0))
                            {
                                parents.get(i+1).getChildren().add(new TreeItem<Employee>(item));
                            }


                        }
                    }

                    treeTableView.setRoot(root);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.out.print(ex.getStackTrace());
                }

                e.setDropCompleted(true);

            }
        });
        VBox boxRoot = new VBox();

        boxRoot.getChildren().add(dropLabel);
        boxRoot.getChildren().add(breadcrum);
        boxRoot.getChildren().add(treeTableView);

        treeTableView.setShowRoot(false);
        treeTableView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
        treeTableView.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);

        sceneRoot.getChildren().add(boxRoot);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }


    public ArrayList<Employee> getChildren(TreeItem<Employee> root, ArrayList<Employee> allItems)
    {
        for(TreeItem<Employee> employeeItem :root.getChildren())
        {
            if(employeeItem.isLeaf())
            {
                allItems.add(employeeItem.getValue());
            }
            else
            {
                getChildren(employeeItem, allItems);
            }

        }

        return allItems;
    }

    public Comparator<Employee> getComparator(String order){
        String[] keys = order.split(";");
        Comparator<Employee> result = Comparator.comparing(gettersMap.get(keys[0]));
        for (int i = 1; i<keys.length; i++){
            result = result.thenComparing(gettersMap.get(keys[i]));
        }
        return result;
    }

    private <T extends Comparable<T>> TreeTableColumn<Employee,T> column(String title, Function<Employee,T> property) {
        TreeTableColumn<Employee,T> col = new TreeTableColumn<>();
        //col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(property.apply(cellData.getValue())));

        Label graphic = new Label(title);
        graphic.setOnDragDetected(e -> {
            groupingComparator = Comparator.comparing(property);
            Dragboard dragboard = graphic.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.COPY);
            ClipboardContent cc = new ClipboardContent();
            cc.putString("Group");
            dragboard.setContent(cc);
        });
        graphic.setOnDragDone(e -> {
            groupingComparator = null ;
        });

        col.setGraphic(graphic);

        return col ;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I can only interpret "Grouping" in a table as performing a stable sort of the items with respect to the field by which you want to group.

You simply need to set up drag and drop here, so that when you drag from the table header and drop onto the label, the table's items are sorted by the property represented by the column. The only tricky part is that there is no easy way to access the table header: the simplest approach is not to set the column text, but to create a label containing the text and set the column graphic to that label. That way you can register the drag handler with the label.

Here is a SSCCE:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.input.ClipboardContent;
import javafx.scene.input.Dragboard;
import javafx.scene.input.TransferMode;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class GroupByTable extends Application {

    public enum Color { GREEN, BLUE, RED }
    public enum Shape { RECTANGLE, CIRCLE, TRIANGLE }
    public enum Size { SMALL, MEDIUM, LARGE }


    private Label groupByLabel;
    private Comparator<Item> groupingComparator ;


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Item> table = new TableView<>();

        table.getColumns().add(column("Size", Item::getSize));
        table.getColumns().add(column("Color", Item::getColor));
        table.getColumns().add(column("Shape", Item::getShape));

        groupByLabel = new Label("Grouping");

        groupByLabel.setOnDragOver(e -> {
            if (groupingComparator != null && "grouping".equals(e.getDragboard().getString())) {
                e.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY);
            }
        });

        groupByLabel.setOnDragDropped(e -> {
            if (groupingComparator != null && "grouping".equals(e.getDragboard().getString())) {
                table.getItems().sort(groupingComparator);
                e.setDropCompleted(true);
            }
        });

        for (Color color : Color.values()) {
            for (Size size : Size.values()) {
                for (Shape shape : Shape.values()) {
                    table.getItems().add(new Item(color, shape, size));
                }
            }
        }

        Collections.shuffle(table.getItems());

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(table);
        BorderPane.setAlignment(groupByLabel, Pos.CENTER);
        BorderPane.setMargin(groupByLabel, new Insets(20));

        root.setTop(groupByLabel);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private <T extends Comparable<T>> TableColumn<Item,T> column(String title, Function<Item,T> property) {
        TableColumn<Item,T> col = new TableColumn<>();
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(property.apply(cellData.getValue())));

        Label graphic = new Label(title);
        graphic.setOnDragDetected(e -> {
            groupingComparator = Comparator.comparing(property);
            Dragboard dragboard = graphic.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.COPY);
            ClipboardContent cc = new ClipboardContent();
            cc.putString("grouping");
            dragboard.setContent(cc);
        });
        graphic.setOnDragDone(e -> {
            groupingComparator = null ;
        });

        col.setGraphic(graphic);

        return col ;
    }

    public static class Item {
        private final Color color ;
        private final Shape shape ;
        private final Size size ;
        public Item(Color color, Shape shape, Size size) {
            super();
            this.color = color;
            this.shape = shape;
            this.size = size;
        }
        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }
        public Shape getShape() {
            return shape;
        }
        public Size getSize() {
            return size;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("%s %s %s", size, color, shape);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Initial screen shot:

[image]

After dragging the "Color" table column header to "Grouping":

[image]

Comment: Is it also possible to replace the table to a treeTableView when the user groups a column (so that all Blue colors are in the same subtree)?

Comment: Yes: you would need to rebuild the tree structure on the drop.

Comment: Tnx did helped me a lot to implement my group by feature.